# dealing with stack using list, erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a stack, I want to push a list into the stack. for eg.

> comp:stack({push,[{{plus,{num,2},{num,2}}}]}, []).

It should then be stored in the stack, something like this

> {{num,2},{num,2},plus} - for eg. push plus will go at bottom, then num2 will go top and the other num2 will go top of that prev num2.

Now I want to pop the whole list and get something like this

> {{num,2},{num,2},plus}

Here is my code so far, all it does is push one and pop one at a time.

```
stack([],StackList) -> [];
stack({push,[H|T]},StackList) -> 
{[H|T]++StackList}.
stack(pop,[StackH|StackT])-> {StackH,StackT}.
```

I am new to er lang, my explanation maybe horrendous to some. Please help me out, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
stack({push, []}, StackList) -> StackList;
stack({push,[H|T]}, StackList) -> 
    stack({push, T}, [H | StackList]);
stack(pop,[StackH|StackT])-> {StackH,StackT}.
```

`stack({push, _}, _)` is called recursively for every element to be pushed.

Use example:

```
1> S0 = comp:stack({push, [plus,{num,2},{num,2}]}, []).
[{num,2},{num,2},plus]
2> {Reg1, S1} = comp:stack(pop, S0).                           
{{num,2},[{num,2},plus]}
3> {Reg2, S2} = comp:stack(pop, S1).
{{num,2},[plus]}
4> {Op, S3} = comp:stack(pop, S2).
{plus,[]}
5> Resault = comp:operation(Op, Reg1, Reg2). %% my guess
6> S4 = comp:stack({push, [Resault]}, S3).
...
```

It is up to you how you want to deal with errors in case of poping from empty stack.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the answers out.

Comment: @nothingness No problem, but take Pascal advice, he's got a point.

Comment: can you explain how i can use this interface or display thing i hear about. Everyone say it makes it easier for them to program in erlang with those.

Comment: @nothingness Stack is simple data structure and if you look how to interfere with other data structure modules like [dict](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html) or [sets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html) you will see common pattern. There is no behaviour (interface) for them, but it start from `NewData = data_type:new()`, and then apply actions specific to them. Your data container is usually the last argument. In your case implement in `stack` module,  `Stack0 = new()`, `{Head, Stack1} = pop(Stack0)`, `Stack1 = push(Elements, Stack0)`, `Boolean = is_empty(Stack)`.  It's just good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The usage in erlang is to create a module dedicated to the management of data structure, and provide some interface to manipulate it. You will find example of this in the stdlib libraries: dict, lists, gb_trees ...

The way you will use is then: `Stack = stack:new()`, `NewStack = stack:push(Value,Stack)`, `{Value,NewStack} = stack:pop(Stack)`... In the case of stack it is quite easy since the erlang list type fit to all usage of stack. You can then write a module:

```
-module(stack).

-export([new/0, push/2, is_empty/1]).

% add your own interfaces

new() -> [].

push(Value,Stack) when is_list(Stack) -> [Value|Stack].

is_empty([]) -> true;
is_empty(Stack) when is_list(Stack) -> false. 

% and so on...
```

Comment: Useful for beginners. Thanks.